# The solar system is open for exploration. What fundamental research will we do first?

Tags: science-based, space-travel, scientific-development

In the near future, technology and budgets for space flight have advanced considerably, with lots of uncrewed probes around and crewed missions as far as Mars. Notably, there's a significant experience with launching large, heavy objects into Orbit and beyond, or building them in space from moon dust & asteroids: If we can build it on earth, we can build it anywhere. We just *greatly* prefer to build stuff that's really low in mass and close to home because the tyranny of the rocket equation still applies and many scientists want to see results of the labour within their lifetime.

For sake of simplicity, this fictional future is far more advanced in terms of rocket engineering and manufacturing (building robots that build robots etc.), but otherwise earth ca. 2020.

This would enable all kinds research, from 100km-scale radioobservatories to sample return missions from the Sun's corona (not really but you get the idea).

What would be fundamental research projects we would tackle first? Fundamental here means advancing our understanding of physics, not cataloging nickel-rich asteroids or discovering unicorn squids on Europa. For inspiration, consider the [list of unsolved problem in Physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unsolved_problems_in_physics).

You'll all do what you like anyway but my preferred answer contains one experiment, the answer shows why it couldnt be done on earth, how the new data gathered might help advance our basic understanding and why *this* project would be one of the first we do if we reach the stage described above.

**ETA:** My aim with this question is to ask, what kind of research stations and satellites could populate a near future solar system. While "Hubble Telescope, but bigger" would be a fitting answer, I'm hoping for weirder stuff (swarm of microwave radiotelescopes to map a solar storm doen to cm scale? A *Super*-large Hadron Collider?) than I can come up with myself.

Comment: Basically we're already doing it. Sending probes to examine & analyse bodies in the solar system. Your scenario suggests we'd do much more of it.

Comment: Whats the budget?

Comment: We wouldn't do anything first, logically if the rockets cost the same, nothing is going to be sent without a full complement of experiments in many fields.

Comment: Don't get hung up on the word "first", that's just there to help you pick *on* idea among the many possible ones.

Comment: It seems that physicists are slowly reaching a concensus that says they first need larger brains, then possibly a even larger hadron collider. ;)

Comment: @Karl yes, that's what I understood for example from here (https://backreaction.blogspot.com/2019/10/has-reductionism-run-its-course.html). I was hard pressed to come up with something more original then "better astronomy." I hoped for the SE hive mind but alas ...

Comment: I wound send four "Gaia" type telescopes to the L4+L5 points of Jupiter & Saturn, equipped with a suitable high bandwidth laser downlink to earth. While at it, four laser communication relay stations in Earths + Mars L4+L5.

Answer (score 0):

### We should master neutrino physics

Neutrino are somewhat a perfect tool for communication as they are almost getting through matter as if it wasn't there.

Therefore, it would be a great way to communicate from A to B regardless of what's in the way… if only we could stop/read them easily.

This would allow for Earth-Mars communication even when the Sun in in the way or between 2 moons of Jupiter.

As some part of Neutrino physics is poorly understood, you can imagine such device could exist

### Muon-catalyzed fusion

This one is more an engineering problem. But a scientific breakthrough would greatly help.

Cold fusion already is a thing as long [as you use muonic hydrogen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muon-catalyzed_fusion).

This has already been tested and can theoretically yield Energy.

The problem is that the Energy curently needed to create a Muon is WAY HIGHER than the theoretical Energy of this particle.

If one can overcome this little problem, this could make a very convenient pocket fusion device

### Understand Fractional Hall effect

This is from the list of unsolved problem you mentionned

I honestly Don't understand much to the wikipedia article, but one can imagine that understanding the [Fractional quantum Hall effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_quantum_Hall_effect) would lead to major breakthough for [Hall-effect thruster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall-effect_thruster)

Comment: How does beeing in space help with generating Muons?

Comment: @mart I Don't know, but generating muon would help going in space. And who knows? Maybe zero-G gravity is just what we need

Comment: Why would neutrino communication be useful? Most of the time, nothing is in your way, and if you *have* to get around sth, its usually no more than pi/2 further.